# iPad4 ignores media query in landscape mode

Tags: css, ipad, media-queries, landscape

I'm trying to create a responsive website. I want to reduce the height of `hgroup` tags if my iPad is in landscape mode, but it ignores my media query. If it's in portrait mode it doesn't ignore my media query anymore.

This is what I've written:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 2048px) and (orientation:landscape)  {
        hgroup {
            height:200px;
        }
}
```

When I'm testing my website at responsivepx.com and resize the browser to 2048px, `hgroup` assumes the 200px height. iPad doesn´t.

I have already searched for a solution and tried a few but none worked for me. For example:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
}
```

Comment: ops, yes. i forget to write it down here but i have that in my CSS

Comment: Ok, I'll delete my answer then. Don't have an iPad4 to test on, so can't really help further than to standard compliance :)

Comment: I´ve found a solution. I wrote:
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (max-height:768px)

instead and now it works on landscape mode